# geom_smooth is not spanning the whole range of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code is drawing the smooth line. But it seems not span through the whole data range. Did I do anything wrong?

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(year, cty)) + geom_jitter() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE, span=3, fullrange=TRUE)
```

It gives me:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried settings ?ggplot2::geom_smooth `fullrange   
should the fit span the full range of the plot, or just the data`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with `geom_jitter`. Looking at the `mpg` dataset it appears there are only two years, 1999 and 2008. `geom_jitter` is making the range appear to be much wider than and it, but `geom_smooth` only draws a line in the range of the data. For example, using

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(year, cty)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE, span=3, fullrange=TRUE)
```

gives us a plot like this instead

[image]

`geom_jitter` is jittering not just the y values (cty) but also the x values (year) which makes it appear as though the date range of the data is wider than it actually is. Since `geom_smooth` only interpolate inside the range, it doesn't span the whole plot like you want.

Comment: It makes perfect sense now. Thanks!!